# Xamarin.iOS: didReceiveLocalNotification did not been called in iOS 8

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My project (build in Xamarin.iOS)use the `UserNotifications`.It works fine after iOS 8.0. However, the method `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` did not been called on my colleagues's iPhone(iOS 8.4.1) when received a notification .I think it has nothing to do with the code, maybe I missed some operations，such as add items in Info.plist before iOS 9.Any suggestions?

```
UNUserNotificationCenter center = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;
center.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge, (bool arg1, NSError arg2) =>
    {

    });

center.Delegate = new NotificationDelegate();
```

I register the NotificationCenter in the method`FinishedLaunching`.It works fine in   simulator and some iPhone(iOS10.3 and iOS 12.0)

Comment: Apple replaced  UIUserNotificationSettings  with  UNUserNotificationCenter  after iOS 10,which one did you use?

Comment: I have  upload my code.@ Lucas Zhang - MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
{
  UNUserNotificationCenter center = UNUserNotificationCenter.Current;
  center.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge, (bool arg1, NSError arg2) =>
  {

  });

  center.Delegate = new NotificationDelegate();
}

else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
{
  var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, new NSSet());
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
}
```